# Run GitLab and Tomcat on the same website URL

Tags: tomcat, gitlab

For the longest time I ran GitLab on HTTP and my Tomcat on HTTPS, but now I would like to run both of them on HTTPS.

I own a website url, lets say its called `https://www.example.com`. I would like to let my tomcat instance handle everything that is not `https://www.example.com/gitlab`. Is this possible? Both services are running on different ports and my problem is, that if I open tomcat first, it will handle all HTTPS requests and if I open GitLab then it will handle all HTTPS requests

Answer (score 0):

Just add Apache or nginx as a reverse proxy before the two services and let them forward the requests.

Comment: Do you mean Tomcat when you say Apache or are you talking about Apache HTTPD?

Comment: The classic web server, httpd